# How to test the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-1-1/n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> How to test the convergence of the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{1+1/n}}?$

Help me. I'm clueless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You for $a_n = \frac1n$ and $b_n = \frac{1}{n^{1+1/n}}$ that
$$
  \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n^{1+1/n}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}n^{-1/n} = 1.
$$
Since $\sum a_n$ diverges, so does $\sum b_n$.

Answer (score 5):

$$
  n<\mathrm e^n\implies n^{1/n}<\mathrm e\implies n^{1+1/n}<\mathrm e\cdot n\implies \frac{1}{\mathrm e\cdot n}<x_n.
$$ 
Since $\sum\frac1{\mathrm e \cdot n}$ is divergent so is the series.

Comment: sriti Mallik puro fatiye diyechoo

Comment: are 2mi 2 bangali ... ki koro 2mi?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach using a higher order ratio test.

Let $a_n = 1/n^{1+1/n}$.
Examining the ratio of successive terms for large $n$ we find
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} = 1 - \frac{1}{n} + O\left(\frac{\log n}{n^2}\right).$$
Therefore, the series diverges by [Gauss's test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssTest.html).