# Find whether a series is divergent or convergent with using the Limit Comparison Test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The problem is:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1+{1\over n}}}$$

How can we determine the following is **converges** or **diverges** with ***Limit Comparison Test***?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1673312/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2054911/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/406652/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%5E%7B1%2B%7B1%5Cover%20n%7D%7D%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: By comparing it with the Harmonic series

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).